# Problems Running Android Emulator - Xamarin, vs 2017

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I'm trying to run a blank Xamarin cross platform application. The UWP app builds and runs in the emulator fine. I uncheck UWP and just build and deploy the Android part and the emulator appears with a black screen but then it hangs for a while and then vs says there were errors. I'm not sure what the problem is. I turned off hyper-v and installed HAXM, am using vs2017 on a pretty fresh windows 10, using the x86 or ARM emulator does the same thing. Here is the output from trying the x86 emulator.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: App3.Android, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  App3.Android -> C:\Users\Daniel\source\repos\App3\App3\App3.Android\bin\Debug\App3.Android.dll
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\tabbar.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\toolbar.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\styles.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\tabbar.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\toolbar.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\styles.xml
2>Starting deploy VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone ...
2>Starting emulator VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone ...
2>D:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone -prop monodroid.avdname=VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone
2>ERROR: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 1emulator: WARNING: userdata partition is resized from 1024 M to 1025 M
2>
2>Hax is enabled
2>Hax ram_size 0x40000000
2>HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
2>audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
2>qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
2>emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
2>emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
2>Emulator VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone is running.
2>Waiting for emulator to be ready...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>...
2>Emulator is not ready to be used.
2>Deploy failed on VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any ideas?